# Manage Spring Boot Profiles with Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build, profile

I have a Spring boot application which is managed by Gradle.

**What is done so far:**

1. Created `application.yaml`, `application-dev.yaml`, and `application-qa.yaml` files
2. Mentioned `spring: profiles: active: dev` in `application.yaml` (default profile should be `dev` if none is mentioned)

**What need to be done:**

1. Need to build `war` with profile mentioned or passed while building. Example, for QA build, `spring: profiles: active:` should have value `qa`, so that it can pick-up `application-qa.yaml` properties.
2. If no profile is passed, then by default `dev` profile should be selected

**What is tried so far:**

1. Added `@activeProfiles@` in `spring: profiles: active: @activeProfiles@` in `application.yaml` and added below snippet in `build.gradle`:

   ```
   processResources {
       filter org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
           activeProfiles: activeProfiles
       ]
   }
   ```

   And fired following command to build the `war` - `gradlew clean build -PactiveProfiles=qa`, and it just did right job for `war` file. But now issue with this approach is, how to provide default value for `activeProfiles` while running the project from IDE (I usually prefer to run `main` class from IntelliJ)?

I am also not sure if this is the correct approach or is there any other approach to achieve this task. I have already done all these stuff with Maven, and with ease, but I am new to Gradle, and it's project requirement to use Gradle.

Comment: I haven't used intelliJ, but sounds like what you need to set up is run configurations.You can provide default run arguments there https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/go-plugin-run-debug-configurations.html

Comment: But what arguments I need to pass and how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066307/how-do-you-input-command-line-arguments-in-intellij-idea
This should help. in eclipse you pretty much provide text `-PactiveProfiles=qa` as the argument. Should be similar with intellij

Comment: @Kasun I tried but it is not working

Comment: I have resolved this issue. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to set default profile, if no profile is passed while running/building the code, using below configurations in `build.gradle` file. No extra configuration is needed in any IDE to run the project.

```
def activeProfiles=project.properties['activeProfiles'] ?: "dev" // set default (dev) profile if no profile is passed as property

processResources {
    filter org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
        activeProfiles: activeProfiles
    ]
}
```

I have 3 yaml files for configurations as per environments:

1. `application.yaml`
2. `application-dev.yaml`
3. `application-qa.yaml`

`application.yaml` contains below configuration for spring profile management, and other common configurations:

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: @activeProfiles@
...
```

`application-dev.yaml` and `application-qa.yaml` files contain configurations related to respective environments.

Answer (score 1):

One common approach to switch between profiles in different environments is to set up `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable to your desired value and let Spring boot use that. For example, in QA environment you would set the value to qa and Spring will automatically use qa application properties.
Read more : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles

Comment: Nah, I don't want to do that. I want to mention profile while running/building the code.